# Solving 3 linear equations with 6 variables, 3 of which are the same across each equation.

Tags: inequality

I feel like I could hash out the answer on my own but am struggling to think of an elegant way to show it.

The equations are as follows:

$$3.5x-2.5y-3z=A$$

$$-7.5x+3.75y+5.25z=B$$

$$4x-1.75y-2z=C$$

I want to find the values of $x$, $y$ and $z$ for which $A$, $B$ and $C$ are all **nonnegative**.

Is there an easy way to visualise and solve this? I have an A level in maths and further maths but don't use them much day to day. If a solution is presented I should be able to follow it though.

Comment: In other words, you want to solve system of inequalities. You probably should reformulate your question

Comment: @MichaelGaluza It looks to me like the OP wants the *constant terms* to be non-negative, not the variables.

Comment: Some first steps:  Sum up all three equations. The variable x will be eleminated. Let denote the resulting equation as a. Now substract the 1.5-fold of the third equation from the first equation. The variable z will be eleminated. Let denote the resulting equation as b. Now solve the equation a for z and the equation b for y. The expressions for z and y can be inserted in one of the posted equations. You will get a expression for x in terms of A,B and C.

Comment: i have got $$ \left\{ x={\frac {20\,C}{37}}-{\frac {18\,A}{37}}-{\frac {8\,B}{111}}
,y=-{\frac {44\,C}{37}}-{\frac {64\,A}{37}}-{\frac {160\,B}{111}},z={
\frac {60\,C}{37}}+{\frac {20\,A}{37}}+{\frac {124\,B}{111}} \right\}
$$